# when/how bootstrap 3.0 decide to start vertically aligning the DOM elements on small sized screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have this sample code inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application, where i am using bootstrap 3.0:-

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 address">
          //Block A         
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 ">
         //Block B
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

now i am defining two blocks inside a row with 4 to 8 occupation, on lg , md & sm screens.. now i am not sure how bootstrap is suppose to work in this case .. i mean i though at the beginning that the occupation which is 4 to 8 will be reserved even on sm screen and the page will show a horizontal toolbar since the two blocks will need more space to have the 4 to 8 occupation on sm screens... but what actually happens is that the two blocks will be vertically aligned (Block A above Block B), when the screen is no more be able to show them on the same row, and no toolbar will be shown... so seems that bootstrap will ignore the col-sm-4 & col-sm-8 if the two blocks will not fit on the same row in the small screen .. so what is the rule the govern the Bootstrap behavioure in this case ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but are you talking about phone screens? Have you tried the "xs" screen size?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not defined the column behiver in xs-screens, bootstrap will not use any column size to thoose div and the width will just be just to auto.
Because the divs has not width, they will have 100% and they will apper one under the other.

Some css frameworks will allow you the define just one size and they will keep it at all screen sizes.
Bootstrap wont...

You just need to add col-xs-4/8

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 address">
          //Block A         
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 ">
         //Block B
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

**edit**

like @Tim Lewis said, becuase bootstrap is mobile-first, you can just define col-xs-4/8 and it will work at all screens.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 address">
          //Block A         
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 ">
         //Block B
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Some css frameworks will allow you the define just one size and they will keep it at all screen sizes. Bootstrap wont..."* Not quite correct. In you only define the `xs` screen size, it will apply it to everything *above* that. So `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8` is all you would need for both of these. Just remember Bootstrap is a **mobile first** framework.

Comment: Awesome! Here's a quick example of how it works: http://www.bootply.com/EK85NzejMs Notice that only `xs` and `md` are set, but `sm` and `lg` both adapt to the size below.

Comment: @TimLewis so if I define col-xs-4 and col-xs-8 then those two divs will always have 4 to 8 on all screens sixes is this correct , I test this and this is the behaviour ??.. second point now let say I added an image to each block (currently the two divs contain html tables) then BlockB will be moved under BlockA  since the image size can not be minimized same as in the table rows.. so if I define col-xs-4 and col-xs-8 and I replace 2 images on BlockA & BlockB then the ratio 4 to 8 will not be applied on small sized screens.. is there any material which describe such behaviours ?

Comment: You are correct about the xs. About the images,  I'm not sure if i understood you correctly. You can set the images to have max-width:100%; this way the will change thier size according to the parent container

Comment: I have also forgat to mention that you will need to add height:auto to the image, this way it will keep the ratio. You can use this link to read more about responsive images in bootstrap:http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images